# How move MediaBox to 0.0 with itext(itextsharp)

Tags: java, c#, itext

The MediaBox coordinate of my PDF file is (-8,-8), now I want to set it (0,0).

I tried to set it directly, but the contents of the file were offset.
So I want to change the MediaBox coordinates and move the content as well.
Here's the itextshare code(c#). I'm glad to be able to solve it with Java itext.

```
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"MediaBoxZero.pdf"))
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(@"MediaBoxZero_Result.pdf", FileMode.Create)))
    {
        var mediaBox = pdfReader.GetBoxSize(1, "media");

        PdfArray mediaBoxN = new PdfArray();
        mediaBoxN.Add(new float[] { 0, 0, mediaBox.Width, mediaBox.Height });

        for (int curPageNum = 1; curPageNum <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; ++curPageNum)
        {
            PdfDictionary pagedict = pdfReader.GetPageN(curPageNum);
            pagedict.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, mediaBoxN);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried affine transformation, but it didn't work. Affine transformation should only work when generating new PDFs, and I wanted to edit existing PDFs.

```
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"MediaBoxZero.pdf"))
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(@"MediaBoxZero_Result.pdf", FileMode.Create)))
            {
                PdfContentByte pb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                at.Translate(100,0);
                pb.Transform(at);
                pb.ConcatCTM(at);
                //var mediaBox = pdfReader.GetBoxSize(1, "media");

                //PdfArray mediaBoxN = new PdfArray();
                //mediaBoxN.Add(new float[] { 0, 0, mediaBox.Width, mediaBox.Height });

                //for (int curPageNum = 1; curPageNum <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; ++curPageNum)
                //{
                //    PdfDictionary pagedict = pdfReader.GetPageN(curPageNum);
                //    foreach (var item in pagedict.GetEnumerator())
                //    {

                //    }
                //    pagedict.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, mediaBoxN);
                //}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Does your C# code as desired and you need help to port it to Java? Or does your C# code cause the problem that *the contents of the file were offset* and you need a working solution for both iText and iTextSharp? Or something different still?

Comment: @mkl This code will cause content offset, because the location of the MediaBox has changed, but the location of the content has not changed.I want to know how to change the location of all content.

Comment: Shifting the page content is feasible, one merely needs to insert an affine transformation up front. This still leaves all the annotations to be also moved. Iterate over them and change their coordinates accordingly. Furthermore, I'm not sure whether patterns will behave well.

Comment: @mkl I tried affine transformation, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'll try and answer later. Actually the `UnderContent` is a bit built to not have its changes to the graphics state bleed through to the existing content, so one has to work around that protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shift the *page contents* like this with iTextSharp to match the **MediaBox** change:

```cs
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SOURCE_PDF))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        Rectangle mediaBox = pdfReader.GetPageSize(i);
        if (mediaBox.Left == 0 && mediaBox.Bottom == 0)
            continue;

        PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfReader.GetPageN(i);
        pageDict.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, new PdfArray { new PdfNumber(0), new PdfNumber(0),
            new PdfNumber(mediaBox.Width), new PdfNumber(mediaBox.Height) });
        Rectangle cropBox = pdfReader.GetBoxSize(i, "crop");
        if (cropBox != null)
        {
            pageDict.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, new PdfArray { new PdfNumber(cropBox.Left - mediaBox.Left),
                new PdfNumber(cropBox.Bottom-mediaBox.Bottom), new PdfNumber(cropBox.Right - mediaBox.Left),
                new PdfNumber(cropBox.Top - mediaBox.Bottom) });
        }
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string translation = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "1 0 0 1 {0} {1} cm\n", -mediaBox.Left, -mediaBox.Bottom);
            byte[] translationBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(translation);
            stream.Write(translationBytes, 0, translationBytes.Length);

            byte[] contentBytes = pdfReader.GetPageContent(i);
            stream.Write(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
            pdfReader.SetPageContent(i, stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"MediaBox-normalized.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fileStream))
    {
    }
}
```

Some remarks:

- You cannot simply manipulate the `UnderContent` of the respective page because iText attempts to prevent changes to the graphics state there (like a change of the current transformation matrix) from bleeding through to the existing content. Thus, here we update the page content on the byte level.
- The code updates the **CropBox** (if set) alongside the **MediaBox**. Strictly speaking it should also update the other boxes known to PDF pages.
- The code ignores annotations. If your PDFs have annotations, you have to also move the annotation **Rect**s and other annotation properties in userspace coordinates, like **QuadPoints**, **Vertices**, etc.